# How do I use Onclick in a div on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using an asp repeater to generate a list of items, each row is a new div. When I click on the row,the row to becomes highlighted and a checkbox that is hidden is checked. To do this I have an id on the div that contains the `Container.ItemIndex` so it looks like:

```
<div class="cartItemInfo" id="cartItemInfo_<%# Container.ItemIndex %>"  OnClick='<%# "return highlightrow(" + Container.ItemIndex +")" %>'>
```

The `onclick` calls this:

```
function highlightrow(RowNum) {
    //alert(RowNum);
    if ($("input[id$=cbRowSelected_" + RowNum + "]").is(':checked')) {
       // alert('IF');

        $("input[id$=cbRowSelected_" + RowNum + "]").attr("checked", false);
        $("div[id$=cartItemInfo_" + RowNum + "]").each(function () { $(this).css("background-color", "inherit") });

    }
    else {
        //alert('ELSE');
        $("input[id$=cbRowSelected_" + RowNum + "]").attr("checked", "checked");
        $("div[id$=cartItemInfo_" + RowNum + "]").each(function () { $(this).css("background-color", "#8A8A8A") });
    }
}
```

When clicked, it calls my jquery and looks to see if the check box is checked, and does what I expected it to do. When I try this  on a phone I run into a problem. When the alerts are uncommentd and I touch the areas on in the list it will tell me the correct row number but would not go into either the if or else.

I've read that `onclick` doesn't work on mobile, and I should you `ontouchstart` instead. But I haven't been able to get that to even tell me what row number I am in.

If I can provide any more info to help solve my problem I will do my best to do so.

Comment: It's been a little bit since I did WebForms, but shouldn't `OnClick` be `OnClientClick`?
Edit: Nevermind, that's for ASP Server Controls... on the same thought though, does `return highlightrow(" + Container.ItemIndex +")` need to be wrapped in `<%# %>`?

Comment: Do you have an example of `onclick` not working?

Comment: @neilsimp1 yes, other wise it will pass a string of _+Container.ItemIndex+_

Comment: @Soren I do not, is there something you were looking for in particular?

Comment: @JoeW How do you know that you have a problem to solve?  Have a look here; http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: @Soren I knew that I had a problem to solve because the function in question was working on all desktops while it did not on any mobile devices. I should have realized the problem wasn't with onclick itself being it would tell me a row number, but we all make mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with onclick, it was the jquery reference. The server that I was on was using https while the reference to the jquery file was http. On mobile devices it would not load the jquery file because of the difference in security. Was able to find the problem after learning of Google Remote Debugging, and gaining access to the developer console.